# Symmetrised Kullback - Leibler divergence

Tags: r, probability, computational-statistics, kullback-leibler, metric

I have trouble understanding KL divergence, where P is probability mass function of true distribution of data and Q is the approximation of P.

The definition of KL divergence is:

$$D_{\mathrm{kl}}(P || Q) = \sum_i \ln\left( \frac{P_i}{Q_i}\right)P_i$$

If I want a symmetrised KL divergence, should it look like the following ?

$$D_{\mathrm{kl}}(P || Q) + D_{\mathrm{kl}}(Q||P) = \sum_i \ln\left( \frac{P_i}{Q_i}\right)P_i + \sum_i \ln\left( \frac{Q_i}{P_i}\right)Q_i$$

Also, which package should I use in R to compute the KL divergence for **discrete distributions** ? Flexmix or FNN ? Or should I just write my own R function for this?

And what if I don't really know  $P$, the true distribution of data?

Answer (score 7):

There are two typical ways to symmetrize the KL divergence:

$$\frac{D(P \| Q) + D(Q \| P)}{2}$$

or

$$\frac{1}{2} D\left(P \; \Big\| \frac{P + Q}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{2} D\left(Q \; \Big\| \frac{P + Q}{2} \right)$$

where $\frac{P+Q}{2}$ means a mixture distribution equally between $P$ and $Q$.

The latter is known as the [Jensen-Shannon divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen-Shannon_divergence) and has some nice properties. The former is also often nice though, and I use it to good effect in some of my own work.

I don't use R, but it's pretty simple to compute this yourself between two discrete distributions defined by vectors with consistent labeling.

In terms of estimation: the continuous case is kind of hard, but [Wang, Kulkarni, and Verdú (2009)](https://www.princeton.edu/~verdu/reprints/WanKulVer.May2009.pdf) give a pretty good estimator based on nearest-neighbor distances. In the discrete case, I'd think that $D(\hat{P} \| \hat{Q})$, where $\hat{P}$, $\hat{Q}$ are any estimate of the density (such as the empirical PMFs) would do fine in most simple cases; I don't know of a direct estimator.

Comment: Do I need to do Jacobian transformation in order to obtain the mixture distribution (P + Q) / 2  ???

Comment: If you have them represented as vectors of probabilities, just literally add the two vectors together and divide by two.